# plotly javascript scatter update data

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to create a scatter diagram that can be updated (data replaced).

```
let init = [{
    x: [1, 3, 4, 200,3],
    y: [16, 0, 11, 100,99],
    mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
}]

let layout = {
    title: 'testing', // updates the title
    'xaxis.range': [0, 500],   // updates the xaxis range
    'yaxis.range': [-3,3]     // updates the end of the yaxis range
};

Plotly.newPlot("chart_test", init, 0);
Plotly.relayout("chart_test", layout,0); //layout applied later, because of auto change.
```

Works fine, plots correctly.
The problem is at changing the data:

```
let style = {
    type:'scatter',
    mode: 'marker'
    x:[1,5,6,70],
    y:[3,4,2,1]
}
Plotly.restyle("chart_test", style);
```

It will change the mode (from line to marker in this example), but the x and y data will not change.

For now, I resort to using Plotly.newPlot() for updating, but that is not efficient.

What am I doing wrong when providing new datapoints?
Could I use Plotly.react() and have the same result as Plotly.restyle()?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
let style = {
    type:'scatter',
    mode: 'marker'
    x:[[1,5,6,70]],  // EDITED <--- array of traces data
    y:[[3,4,2,1]]     // EDITED <--- array of traces data
}
Plotly.restyle("chart_test", style);
```